# Does FormsAuthenticationModule detect whether …?

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, httpmodule

*FormsAuthenticationModule* is used for tracking user and role information using encrypted cookie.

But does this module also contain code that actually detects whether user requesting web page has  forms authentication ticket and if not, redirects user to login page, or is it actually *UrlAuthorizationModule* that tells *FormsAuthenticationModule* to redirect unauthorized/unauthenticated user to the login page?

thanx

Comment: Forms Authentication knows absolutely nothing about roles.  I fyou want to use roles with Forms Authentication then you have to teach it about roles yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough, I just researched this this week.

It turns out that the FormsAuthenticationModule does do the actual redirect in EndRequest event handler.  However, it doesn't decide that the redirect should happen.  It does the redirect if the response status code is 401 (Unauthorized).

The UrlAuthorizationModule is the place where the decision is made (as mentioned in another answer), but all it does is indicate that the request is not authorized by setting the response status code to 401.

So, it is actually the two modules in coordination that make the redirect to the login page happen.

Comment: Fair enough :) Indeed, the listing on Koders seems to indicate that the redirect on 401 happens in the AuthenticationModule (http://bit.ly/s7eiX).

Comment: I noticed this in the Mono source for FormsAuthenticationModule, and wondered why it waited until EndRequest. This makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, the [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule_members.aspx) only

> Sets the identity of the user for an ASP.NET application when forms authentication is enabled.

However, looking around elsewhere (props to [Erv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860361/does-formsauthenticationmodule-detect-whether/860994#860994) for pointing this out) the forms authentication module is then responsible for redirecting the user to the login page by hooking into the application's [EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx) Event

This means it has nothing to do with with roles - roles are handled by the [RoleManagerModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.rolemanagermodule.aspx)

So the [UrlAuthorizationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule_members.aspx) uses the Authentication Module (i.e. Forms, [Passport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.passportauthenticationmodule.aspx)/Live, [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationmodule.aspx), etc) and Role provider (using which Role module is appropriate) that are configured in the web config to enforce access, and if the [CheckUrlAccessForPrinciple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal.aspx) that's actually checking the users access rights returns false, a 401 error is raised, and this is then returning to ASP.NET to handle.

The app then raises the EndRequest Event, which is picked up by the FormsAuthenticationModule which finally redirects the user to the Default login page defined in the Forms auth section of the web.config.